# Force Bootcamp 6.0 to use the new ISO Windows installation without USB stick

Tags: bootcamp, usb, macos

It is now possible to install Windows directly with an ISO since OSX El Capitan release : https://help.apple.com/bootcamp/assistant/6.0/#/bcmp173b3bf2. We no longer need to have a USB stick or a superdrive.

However, in my case (Macbook Pro early 2011 without superdrive), I can't see this proposition, I only have the old way.

I know it was possible to force the system to do a USB stick OSX installation by changing the plist.info. Can we do the same to enable this new functionality on old Macbook Pro ?

I try to install Windows 10.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that machines is not supported in Boot Camp 6. It would help to know what version of Windows you are trying to install too.

Comment: Yes, I think that my laptop is not supported, but maybe we can change an information to force the functionality, as I had to do to make a windows installation USB stick.

I try to install windows 10.